# Xamarin.forms a CarouselPage in a relative layout

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, slideshow

I want to have a login in xamarin that have an slideshow in background. for this reason I implement an Slideshow using xamarin CarouselPage. but now I want to have a simple login form on slideshow. but RelativeLayout only accept View or List. how can I implement such design with xamarin.forms?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommendations of Xamarin people regarding your problem are : 
 1. Almost never use a RelativeLayout becuase it a cause of bad performance, so you can use a grid or a stacklayout instead . 
 2. sooner or later the CarouselPage will be obsolete. Plus since you cannot use it because you cannot put a page as a part of a ContentPage so use [CarouselView](https://blog.xamarin.com/flip-through-items-with-xamarin-forms-carouselview/). It is the new thing from Xamarin.

Comment: now I use Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView. but I want slides play automatically. how can I handle this?